# How to get ObservableCollection from Dictionary Values

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have an `ObservableCollection<MyClass> myCollection` and a `Dictionary<int, MyClass> myDictionary`.

How would I copy all the Values of Class `MyClass` from the `Dictionary` to the `ObservableCollection`?
Unfortunately this won't work (Cannot implicitly convert type...):

```
myDictionary = myCollection.Values
```

And I was hoping for a solution that would perform better than:

```
       for (int i = 0; i < myDicitonary.Values.Count; i++ )
            myCollection.Add(myDicationary.Values.ElementAt(i));
```

Comment: FROM Dictionary TO ObservableCollection? Your code example tries to do it the other way around (from collection to dict). Do you have a typo in your question?

Comment: It looks like you want it the other way around, from the collection to the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks to you two, just changed it!

Answer (score 9):

The observable collection can be created from an IEnumerable.

```
myCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(myDictionary.Values)
```

If you already have the collection created and don't want to create a new one, you'd have to iterate trough myDictionary.Values and manually add each value in the observable collection. Note that this will trigger the collection changed event after each individual add.

Comment: thanks! Great solution, especially since I didnt want to trigger the changed event every `Add()`